# Java drawing values on a height scale meter cuts off the string

Tags: java

I am creating a height scale in km based on a 0 to 3 km range, where 3km is red and 0 is blue, so a scale between blue and red.

I successfully made the scale, and now I want to place text on the scale to approxly show the height every 25px on the scale:

```
private void drawHeightScale(Graphics2D g2d) {

    // Scale meter dimensions
    int scaleHeight = 300;
    int scaleWidth = 50;

    // Scale meter position
    int x = getBoss().getWidth() - (scaleWidth + 10);
    int y = getBoss().getHeight() - (scaleHeight + 10);

    // the maximum allowed height
    double max = 3;

    // the current height for scale drawing
    double current = max;

    // The color ratio
    double ratio = 255 / max;

    // Current Y to draw scale line color
    int currentY = y;

    // How much to decrease from height every time starting from height max
    float decreaseRatio = (float) (max / 255);


    // setting font for the text on the meter
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10);
    g2d.setFont(font);

    // Iterate through scale height to draw each color line to create a meter
    for (int i = 0; i < scaleHeight; i++) {

        // Red value
        float r = (float) (current * ratio);

        // Blue value
        float b = 255 - r;

        // Draw meter
        g2d.setColor(new Color(r / 255, 0, b / 255));
        g2d.fillRect(x, currentY, scaleWidth, 1);

        // start drawing text
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        // Do it every 50px
        if (i % 50 == 0) {

            String n = formater.format(current) + " Km";
            g2d.drawString(n, x + (scaleWidth / 2) - g2d.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(n) / 2, y + i);
        }

        // Decrease 
        if (current  >=  decreaseRatio ) {
            current -=  decreaseRatio ;
        }

        // Next y
        currentY++;
    }
}
```

Now every thing is fine, but for some reason I have an offset, as in the text doesnt draw on the right y:

[image: img]

So I tried to add  `y+3`:

```
g2d.drawString(n, x + (scaleWidth / 2) - g2d.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(n) / 2, (y + 3) + i);
```

And this is what I got:

[image: img2]

The text gets cut off it's height, and I can't really see the reason for this, besides something in the API.

What did I do wrong there?

Comment: Looks like the text starts to draw at the right position, but it just drawing the text from bottom to top, but dont get why it cuts off the text if i push it downer

Comment: That's because you're drawing red/blue rows of pixel on your string labels. Separate the two operations in two different for loops (first draw the colored lines, then draw the strings), it should fix the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are drawing a rect after that a text. The rect is drawing over text..

1. rect
2. text
3. rect ---> this rect is drawing over 1. text
4. text
   ...
   ...

try to first draw rects after draw the texts...